# Restoring from checkpoint when variable shape changes

Tags: tensorflow

I'm unable to restore checkpointed models that include variables that change shape. For example with this simple model:

```
var = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.constant_initializer([0]), shape=[1], trainable=False, name='var')
op = tf.assign(var, [1, 2], validate_shape=False)
saver = tf.train.Saver(reshape=False)
```

if I run `op` and then save the model, when I try to restore it I get the following error:

```
Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [1] rhs shape= [2]
 [[Node: save/Assign = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](var, save/restore_slice)]]
```

which seems to have to do with the changing shape and `Saver` trying to validate shape. If I set `reshape` to `True` when constructing the `Saver`, which according to the docs should solve this problem, I instead get this error:

```
Input to reshape is a tensor with 2 values, but the requested shape has 1
 [[Node: save/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](save/restore_slice, save/Reshape/shape)]]
```

I'm inclined to think that this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The reshape option to `Saver` only works if the shapes have the same total number of elements.  For example, it will let you load a variable with shape `[1]` from data with shape `[]`, or a variable with shape `[15, 7]` from data with shape `[5, 21]`.  If the shapes aren't compatible in this way, you'll have to build a new graph.

Answer (score 0):

Set `validate_shape` to False when loading meta graph by adding code

```
if graph.node[-1].attr.get("validate_shape"):
    graph.node[-1].attr["validate_shape"].b = False
```

to tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#2318

```
with self._lock:
  graph = graph_pb2.GraphDef()
  graph.versions.CopyFrom(self._graph_def_versions)
  bytesize = 0
  for op_id in sorted(self._nodes_by_id):
    op = self._nodes_by_id[op_id]
    if from_version is None or op_id > from_version:
      graph.node.extend([op.node_def])
      if graph.node[-1].attr.get("validate_shape"):
        graph.node[-1].attr["validate_shape"].b = False
      if op.outputs and add_shapes:
        assert "_output_shapes" not in graph.node[-1].attr
        graph.node[-1].attr["_output_shapes"].list.shape.extend([
            output.get_shape().as_proto() for output in op.outputs])
      bytesize += op.node_def.ByteSize()
      if bytesize >= (1 << 31) or bytesize < 0:
        raise ValueError("GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.")
```