# How create new graph starting from a previous model in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

My goal is save an tensorflow model and restore it, but with different shape variables (I want add new classes and new training examples).
In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585053/restoring-from-checkpoint-when-variable-shape-changes) it's explained that the option reshape of Saver works if the shapes have the same total number of elements, and it's necessary to build a new graph.
My question is: Is possible to build a new graph with the old trained model? So that resume the training with the new class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize shared part of the model from old checkpoint. Please take a look to: `tf.contrib.framework.init_from_checkpoint`

Comment: ok thanks, it works fine. I used the official docs [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/contrib.framework/checkpoint_utilities#init_from_checkpoint)